# How to mutate with ifelse within a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a function using ifelse but keep getting an error message. I want to create a flag variable that populates a 1 if both of two variables = `abs(1)`, and a 0 otherwise

I can get code to run by inputting 2 specific variables, but am having trouble turning that into a function. Any help is appreciated!

```
#this is the code I got to work
df <- df %>%
mutate(Flag=ifelse(PTO_1== abs(1) && PTO_2 == abs(1), 1, 0))

#now trying to turn it into a function
flag <- function(var1,var2) {
df <- df %>%
mutate(Flag=ifelse(var1== abs(1) && var2 == abs(1), 1, 0))
}

#trying out the function, and get an error message
flag(PTO_1,PTO_2)
```

I expect a new 'flag' variable to be created, but instead get an error message:

> object 'PTO_1' not found

Comment: Why are you using `abs(1)`, given this will always simply be `1` ?

Comment: This "just" has to do with `dplyr` NSE. Take a look at `enquo`,`sym` and `!!` or more recently `{{}}` from `rlang`. More details [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error message because `PTO_1` is, as the error message implies, not a variable in your environment.

```
df <- data.frame("PTO_1" = rpois(n = 5, lambda = 1),
                 "PTO_2" = rpois(n = 5, lambda = 1))
  PTO_1   PTO_2
1     1       3
2     2       2
3     0       0
4     1       1
5     0       1

#define the function to take the variable vectors as inputs:
flag <- function(x,y) {
  Flag <- as.numeric(x == 1 & y == 1)
  return(Flag)
}

#use mutate to send those variables through the function
df %>% mutate(Flag = flag(PTO_1, PTO_2))

  PTO_1 PTO_2 Flag
1     1     3    0
2     2     2    0
3     0     0    0
4     1     1    1
5     0     1    0
```